# Are most applicants really unable to implement FizzBuzz in an interview?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, graduate

**Are a large proportion of programming job applicants unable to implement FizzBuzz (or a similarly simple task)?**

On the blog Coding Horror, Jeff Atwood quotes individuals as saying that a large number of programming job applicants are unable to implement FizzBuzz. [Why Can't Programmers.. Program?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/)

> [Quoting [Don't Overthink FizzBuzz](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/01/dont-overthink-fizzbuzz.html)]
>
> > Like me, the author is having trouble with the fact that [199 out of 200](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2005/01/27.html) applicants for every programming job can't write code at all. I repeat: **they can't write any code whatsoever**.
>
> The author he's referring to is Imran, who is evidently [turning away lots of programmers who can't write a simple program](https://imranontech.com/2007/01/24/using-fizzbuzz-to-find-developers-who-grok-coding/):
>
> > Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz".
> >
> > Most good programmers should be able to write out on paper a program which does this in a under a couple of minutes. Want to know something scary? **The majority of comp sci graduates can't.** I've also seen self-proclaimed senior programmers take more than 10-15 minutes to write a solution.

This question was partially prompted by [this unanswered skeptics exchange post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32780/are-a-large-proportion-of-programming-job-applicants-unable-to-implement-fizzbuz) .

Is there something wrong with our colleges? Are people panicking? Is it a good thing to ask in an interview?

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this majority of comp sci graduates gets eventually a job and if so, where.

Comment: Your question title focusses on comp-sci graduates but the main question in your body is about job applicants ("Are a large proportion of programming job applicants"). Please clarify if you are interested in job applicants of all levels, fresh comp-sci graduates, comp-sci graduates in general.

Comment: @Joe It's not deleted, the link was just wrong.

Comment: @BernhardBarker Ah thanks for fixing!

Comment: Worth remembering: That post was written 13 years ago.

Comment: @FrankHopkins I'm interested in either I guess. I'm interviewing graduates who are applicants. I've clarified the language to applicants just to be clear.

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to find a reputable source, that's why the original post on Skeptics is unanswered. I tried to answer the Skeptics post with my personal experience but that isn't good enough for their standard of proof.

Comment: That blog post is over a *decade* old. That is *ancient* in this industry. Doesn't mean it is or isn't still a valid gripe, but read it with a grain of salt due to it's age.

Comment: I think that many of the answers and comments take it as axiomatic that fizzbuzz failure => bad hire. It's not necessarily true. There is no ONE question that can definitively screen out applicants. Fizzbuzz is absolutely trivial if you make use of the modulo operator. The problem is not everyone knows the modulo operator, or if they do, they might have forgotten the symbol or some details of how it's supposed to work (eg does X mod N go from 1 to N or 0 to N-1). If so, they might abandon using modulo and end up painting themselves into a corner, too embarrassed to relax and think it though

Comment: What's FizzBuzz?

Comment: @David it's a computer programming question. It's really simple, and somewhat surprisingly works really well as a weeder to eliminate people who don't know how to program but applied for a programming job. It's especially interesting because it's been a poster-child weeder question for well over 10 years now and despite being high-profile *still* manages to function effectively.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Yes - and that makes the exercise useful for the interviewer!

I've been on the hiring panel for Software Engineering jobs, and programmer applicants straight out of uni are universally unable to do the following:

- Write FizzBuzz (or a similar simple program.)
- From only the specifications alone, without any help from the interviewers
- In the programming environment of the company
- In under 15 minutes.
- Without Googling.
- And have it compile without errors.
- And run correctly first time.

... and that's a good thing because "How good a programmer you are" isn't the main focus of what we're testing for in an interview for a programming job - we want to know how good a programmer you'll *become*. It's going to take you 3 months to get up to speed (learn our libraries, standards, etc), we want to preview how good you'll be in 3 months by watching you fail and learn. If everyone got it in 5 minutes it wouldn't tell us anything useful about the interviewee. We want to see you try, fail, investigate the failure, ask for help, debate ideas, take advice, and work with the interviewer to develop the software together.

After explaining FizzBuzz to an interviewee, we explain that we're here to help and bounce ideas off. The interviewee will then attempt to write the code using multiple if statements. They'll usually predict the mod 15 case, but will mess up something trivial (like it may print the number after FizzBuzz, or there'll be a missing newline, or such), or it wont compile. 50% of the time they'll spot their error(s) and fix it within a few attempts without help.

When they really screw up, its usually because their uni taught them Java or something, and we were looking for a C++ developer. We do say that C++ experience is preferred but not required, so there's often questions asked about syntax, or cryptic compiler errors. **We want you to ask these**, it helps us understand how you think.

If they do get it too early without help, we'll try to make the challenge harder. "Excellent; Now do it with only 1 print statement.", or "Now do it without duplicating Fizz and Buzz for the FizzBuzz case", "Now do it without using an 'if'", "Now do it without an if or a '?' operator."

We need to see you solve a problem to figure out how good a developer you'll be. Most people will get FizzBuzz wrong first few attempts, spot their mistakes, and fix it on their own. That debugging and reasoning and diagnostic process is what we want to see, and if we see that, and you can communicate with the interviewer about your problems, issues, and ideas, then you'll get through to the next round of interviews.

The FizzBuzz exercise is also really an ice breaker. We'll get you on harder problems within 15 minutes. We just want to get a feel for your problem solving ability.

Comment: Somewhat orthogonal to your point, but a programmer who routinely uses lots of different languages would have at best a 50:50 chance of hitting the "have it compile without errors... first time" target, because of the need to guess whether the particular language s/he's using on this occasion has "elsif" or "elseif".

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't heavily downvoted considering the third-to-last paragraph about variations. For some reason people *hate* these "unrealistic" interview questions.

Comment: @user253751 I got asked one of these variations in my interview, and I've asked it when interviewing others. We're not testing "realism", we're testing how you think and learn and solve problems.

Comment: IDK about "run correctly the first time".  That seems more like a typing test than a programming one.  After more years of programming than I care to remember, I still make the occasional typo - just as I do when posting comments here.

Comment: @jamesqf Isn't it the point in this answer? You are expected to write it incorrectly the first time. Then if you can or ask good questions that help you fix the problems, or fix them yourself, then you pass that task and the interview continues with more serious questions. Some people also have it run correctly the first time, but that's fine and they pass to the next question as well.

Comment: So you reject all candidates who don't already know your company's preferred language, or a closely related one?

Comment: @stannius No, we want to see you learn in the interview so we understand what you'll be like in 3 months when you actually are up to speed. I knew 0 c++ in my interview and had to do it in c++. I didnt get it first time, but i got the job, because I asked questions and worked with the interviewer.

Comment: Well, shoot. I just tried FizzBuzz with Python. Simple text editor, without syntax highlighting or anything. I forgot the `i` in `for i in range(1, 101):`, and it only ran correctly the second time :-/

Comment: Are you working in a domain were code-golfing is a relevant skill? Otherwise, those exercises seem an extremely poor idea. As a candidate, I'd probably think twice if I'd want to work somewhere where golfing is more important than writing correct, easy to read and thus easy to maintain & easy to change code.

Comment: @jamesqf The post didn't say it had to *compile* first time. So your argument about typos is irrelevant. If your idea of "a "typo includes "accidentally typing the wrong variable name" or "typing + when you meant -", that's not a typo, it's a logic error - or making a poor choice of variable names which are too similar to each other.

Comment: "And run correctly first time." will leave out all programmers doing TDD. To be fair though, 99% of programmers doing TDD in an interview will decide they don't want to work with you as soon as they hear that requirement, so they're vetting you before you're vetting them.

Comment: Getting it compile and run without errors in company environment one did not have any chance to familiarize himself with seems pretty weird requirement. If documentation for that environment is detailed enough to be sure to do this, it might take more than 15 minutes to even *read* it, depending on language of course. Unless this is an environment like "Visual Studio, C#, nothing extra, clean install".

Comment: @Mołot it seems that the candidate isn't allowed to use internet resources e.g. the documentation, making it moot how long it would take to read it.

Comment: @Polygnome Exactly; unreadable code is useless.  COBOL took it a litle too far, though :)

Comment: @Mołot Under the circumstances described, it makes sense, but *as an interviewee* I'd be extremely put off and may walk out... unless it was explained in advance that this was a Kobayashi Maru sort of deal.

Comment: Feel like it's worth pointing out that this is a bit different than fizzbuzz as presented in the blog post: Atwood was complaining that applicants could not write fizzbuzz, *in any language*. If you let me pick the language I could rattle off fizzbuzz as fast as I can write it, and could before I ever had a programming job. You're talking about having applicants write it in a potentially unfamiliar language, which is way different.

Comment: At some point I had a compiler that would compile one file _really_ fast. So to save brain power, I would start writing code, leave out things like variable declarations, don't check for typos, the compiler shows me the first problem, I fix it, compiler shows me the next problem etc. Faster than trying to compile it right first time, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 109):

There is a deeper phenomenon here:

**The majority of applicants for any given job are below average**

That sounds counter-intuitive, right? But, think for a moment.

- *Good* applicants get jobs quickly. They go for an interview, maybe two, they have a pleasant chat with the interviewer, they answer the questions correctly, they get an offer.
- *Bad* applicants interview over, and over, again, until they find an employer whose application process is loose enough to take them on.

So suppose you have:

- 10 good applicants, going to 2 interviews each before getting a job.
- 10 bad applicants, going to 20 interviews each before getting a job.

That's 220 interviews total, and 200 of those interviews are with a bad candidate.

Now imagine you are a company doing 10 interviews total.
How many bad candidates will you see?

So, the figures given don't seem unrealistic to me, but they are representative of graduate applicants *for a given job*, not of all graduates.

Comment: Why does "bad candidate" imply "not able to implement FizzBuzz"? Your logic does would also be valid if "bad candidate" means something else.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my point. 99% of “candidates” is not the same as 99% of current programmers. The pool of interview candidates is biased toward the bottom.

Comment: So your answer is not about "not being able to programm FizzBuzz", do I see this right?

Comment: If you mean, could the question be generalised to "why do the majority of candidates for a technical role fail a simple proficiency test?", then yes, I think it could. I see the question as a specific example of a more general problem.

Comment: Yes, I meant if your answer explains if or if not 199 out of 200 can not program FizzBuzz or if it only explains that in any given setting, most candidates are worse than most workers.

Comment: IMHO your definition of Good and Bad are incorrect.  Companies hire people who they feel are "Suitable" for a role.  And what one company considers suitable may not be what another company considers suitable.  Thus a candidate who only gets an offer after N+1 interviews may simply have been applying for N jobs for which they were not suitable, and not because they were a bad candidate.  And this isn't even considering that the interviewers in those first N interviews were not capable fo doing *their* job.

Comment: "until they find an employer whose application process is loose enough to take them on." or until they apply for a lower or simply different position, one for which they are good applicants.

Comment: @PeterM I'd argue that "bad candidate" and "not suitable candidate" are equivalent in this context.  That doesn't mean a person who can't code is a bad/unsuitable candidate for every job in the world, but they certainly are for programming jobs.

Comment: I see your logic, and it makes a lot of sense, but wouldn't these bad applicants who keep applying over and over learn the basic puzzles after failing them a few times? Doesn't this mean you'd then have bad applicants tending to pass FizzBuzz (they've had practice) and good applicants fresh out of uni failing it because its their first interview?

Comment: @guest: Bad candidate doesn'timply "can't implement FizzBuzz", but "can't implement FizzBuzz" does imply "bad candidate". Think of it this way: the question "why do bees die?" can be answered by "because all animals die". "animal" does not imply "bee" (just like "bad candidate" does not imply "can't implement FizzBuzz"); but "bee" does imply "animal" (just like "can't implement FizzBuzz" implies "bad candidate").

Comment: @Flater: Sure. But if a question is "Can so many applicants not implement FizzBuzz" and the answer is "In every interview there have are many bad candidates", we need the implication "bad candidates cannot implement FizzBuzz". Suppose a world where everybody/nobody/10/40% could implement FizzBuzz. Then this answer "In every interview there are many bad candidates" is still correct (by the logic explained in the answer) - so how can it say if many people cannot implement FizzBuzz?

Comment: @guest **(1)** _"we need the implication "bad candidates cannot implement FizzBuzz""_ You seem to have misunderstood the order of logical consistency. You don't need the implication that every bad developer cannot implement fizzbuzz, you need the implication that every developer who can't implement fizzbuzz is a bad developer. **(2)** _"so how can it say if many people cannot implement FizzBuzz?"_ That is **precisely** what this answer explains, i.e. how the "many" in the context of interviews is biased towards those who are not already offered a job, **because they're a bad developer**.

Comment: @guest **(3)** _"and the answer is "In every interview there have are many bad candidates""_ That's not an accurate summary of the answer. An accurate summary of the answer is "[this] is why the ratio of bad developers in a pool of applicants for developer positions is disproportionately higher than the ratio of bad developers in a pool of hired developers". Coupled with the (admittedly implicit) assertions that developers who cannot implement FizzBuzz are bad developers, the answer succinctly addresses why FizzBuzz-challenged developers are disproportionately common in a pool of applicants.

Comment: @PeterM: The answer doesn't actually provide definitions for Good and Bad. Contextual to the question, the distinction can be understood here to be the ability to implement FizzBuzz, but in truth this applies to any reasonably Good/Bad definition. And while you are correct that some companies may value/weight things differently, a general lack of basic development skill (which is what failing to implement any workable FizzBuzz strongly implies) is never really going to be considered a positive when dealing with applicants to development positions.

Comment: @Flater: No. Imagine that everybody in the World could implement FizzBuzz. Then the answer to the question above is "no, this is not correct". Now, this answer argues that most applicants are bad (correctly). But they could also be bad because they cannot implement BuzzFizz. So how can this question answer if really a majority of applicants cannot implement FizzBuzz?

Comment: @Flater: Indeed, I would say that maybe 50 out of 200 applicants cannot implement FizzBuzz and 199 out of 200 are not suitable because of any reason (no people skills etc.) So I could post the same answer as this one, but with the conclusion "The figures given above seem unrealistic to me."

Comment: @guest: **No one has claimed 199 out of 200 developers cannot write FizzBuzz**. Not this answer, not the question, not Jeff Atwood (quoted by the question poster). You're trying to argue the unrealistic nature of an argument that no one but you made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113402/discussion-between-guest-and-flater).

Comment: @Flater: I myself have not claimed this. I am alwaya talking about appliciants.

Answer (score 25):

While I agree with most of the existing answers, this is another issue:

> Most good programmers should be able to write out on paper a program which does this in a under a couple of minutes.

**Many good programmers are not very comfortable with paper programming**. Yes they should be able to explain and develop an algorithm on paper, but they might feel out of their comfort zone when they need to actually program with somewhat correct syntax on paper. This is more a behavioural instinct that gets in the way than a sign of not being able to program. They are instinctively programmed to type on a keyboard and get the "unimportant stuff" added automatically, it's awkward and just may take some time to suddenly go back to doing everything manually. So at least they might get slower and be distracted by the challenge to remember the correct syntax. While paper tests often are not about correct syntax (and good ones imho never should be), that impression might come across easily and startle the candidate. So, if you design your paper tests badly the likelihood you will see people struggle that would normally perfectly fit for your programming job also increases.

Comment: I would refuse to produce anything but high-level pseudo-code on paper. I frigging don't write syntactically correct code, not with pen & paper. Writing pseudo-code (in whatever fashion you choose) should be enough to demonstrate that one can understand a problem and develop a solution.

Comment: @Polygnome It's like trying to play accurately on an air guitar

Comment: @DKNguyen Hey, my air guitar solos are awesome and melodically and rhythmically perfect!

Comment: @DKNguyen - Speaking as a guitarist, if I was asked to demonstrate fingering on an imaginary fretboard, I could do it. Similarly as a programmer I could scribble something on paper that outlined an algorithm even though my handwriting has deteriorated massively through using computer keyboards for everything.

Comment: @Polygnome can I steal-quote you next time someone asks this? =)

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica Is it actually accurate though without a fretboard? I play piano and violin and I wouldn't be able to get the fingerings the right positions in the air without some physical feedback. I can do it right now and you would clearly see that my fingers don't fall in the same horizontal plane in a mime-like fashion against a non-existent fretboard

Comment: @OnoSendai Sure.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Sure. I suppose my parallel is between writing syntax-perfect-instantly-compilable code and scribbling an efficient algorithm on a sheet of paper. I could certainly do the latter, as I could play pretty convincing air-guitar.

Comment: When I was in college, I can code fine on paper. After being a web developer for 10 years, dealing with HTML/CSS, all the flavors of Javascript, PHP, .NET, all forms of databases, etc, etc, etc, I make sure I reference the specific API before writing real code. There's no way I can remember over a dozen different syntaxes that functionally do the same thing but are not syntactically identical. Even something SUPER basic like `obj(0)` is very different depending on language. This is an array call in VB.NET, but a function call in most other languages.

Comment: I always wondered why not give them a computer and simulate how the job would actually be done

Comment: @David well, if you do it right, you don't want actual executable code but a quick sketch of an algorithm in pseudo code thus saving you and them the time to deal with language + syntax specifics. So imho, paper tests can make sense, but you need to stress that the outcome doesn't need to be a runnable program. (And personally I find it easier to get into that mindset when writing on a writeboard, but that's another topic then^^)

Comment: @FrankHopkins You're probably right. My comment comes from my bias as an R user, who can't conceive the possibility of non-runnable code!

Answer (score 14):

I feel like [Joe's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/164166/2909) is enlightening in that it does explain that the pool of interviewees thins out naturally due to the fact that a good candidate can find a job quicker than a bad candidate.

My response is [aligned with Ash's](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/164163/2909) in that this is a simple **problem solving exercise**.

I've conducted interviews at my current employer for several years now, and the ultimate goal and objective that I have is that I want to see:  if I give you a problem and some resources to approach it, are you able to solve it, or do you freeze up?

FizzBuzz is beloved (or loathed) for the ability to gently introduce the notion of, "how do you solve a problem?"  It eliminates any contextual awareness or notion of state, and it makes the environment or frame of reference entirely sterile and uniform.  Everyone gets the same question and gets to answer it in their own way.  There's enough pitfalls in it that some interviewers could isolate a form of "talent" or a form of "oh, this person can solve a problem".

While I emphatically disagree that FizzBuzz is fit for the purpose of problem solving - I've only ever used it once and immediately regretted it - the bigger and broader question that the article is addressing is that graduates may not know how to problem solve.

Having done this, my specific answer to this is anecdotal, but the real issue isn't that applicants don't know how to program.  It's that **applicants don't know how to problem solve**, and they fill their resume with all of the signatures and finger prints of having solved problems, but when pushed on those fronts, their achievements ring hollow.

Programming can be taught; it takes a period of time with the right resources and an environment that facilitates education for that to happen or manifest itself.  Problem solving is more nuanced in that there's no formula or pattern that can be applied; unlike FizzBuzz which is really there just to weed out people who don't know how to use modulo (which - again - can just be taught!), asking an applicant to solve a problem or how to approach a problem is the ultimate crux of interviews.

We get a lot of graduates who have relied on writing code as a way to get their degree, but when faced with the prospect of actually solving a problem, they crumble.

Comment: This. you correctly point out that fizzbuzz is kinda gimmicky with the "has this person come across the modulus operator before", but that there are simple things we expect people to be able to do.

Comment: It is easy, but maybe slightly ugly, to write fizzbuzz without modulo operator. The difficult part is that you need to write a loop, some conditionals and print out text and numbers. Yes, those are trivial too but somehow people still manage to fail.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't necessarily meant to contradict the existing answers about selection bias or performance anxiety. They're good. But I want to address a specific part of your question:

> Is there something wrong with our colleges?

Yes. Or no. Depends on perspective. But I'm going to relay two conversations that I had in the last few years with two different computer science undergrads that may shed some light on this. Names (other than mine) have been changed for privacy of the participants.

"Greg" was a compsci undergrad at Purdue, which while perhaps not quite on the level of a Stanford/MIT/CMU is still pretty high up there in terms of US compsci programs (top ten?). If you asked Greg at that time about what his favorite language(s) was/were, or what personal projects he was working on, he could talk your ear off about it. I privately coached Greg in sports, and we had a lot of great tech conversations as well.

"Bob" was an undergrad in compsci at Podunk State that I wound up by chance sitting across from at a dinner for an unrelated activity about the same time. When it came up that he was a computer science student, I being a software engineer immediately started to ask the same sorts of questions I mentioned above, both because it makes for interesting conversation and also to see if I could nudge him into the recruiting pipeline. It became very apparent very quickly that Bob had never written a line of code in his life that wasn't for a class assignment. You might chalk that up to him not being very interested in programming, but based on other clues in the conversation it seemed more that he thought *excessively* inside the box. He did what he was told, the idea that he should have his own interests seems to either have not occurred or was more likely beat out of him at some point.

Greg has never applied for a job in his life. Any job. He didn't work in high school, he was recruited to be an intern by a prestigious household-name NYC company, then got a job offer as a data scientist for said company, then worked part time for them while finishing his degree and now works full time for them.

I lost track of Bob but Bob almost certainly graduated with a real-life CS degree from a real-life university. And given the burgeoning demand for software engineers he probably found some job, somewhere. But it must have been a struggle: *I* certainly wouldn't have hired him.

We often say the degree or the institution doesn't really matter. And to a large degree that's true: my degree isn't even in Computer Science, and I went to the same university as Bob. But the *person* matters a lot.

Except for top-tier programs universities in the United States do not do a good job of policing this. You can skate by doing C-level work in a mediocre program and still graduate and the university's incentives are totally in favor of letting you do just that. But the real problem is more subtle: people who are only *capable* of *at best* C-level work can skate by and graduate. And perhaps in a narrative discipline you can get away with that when you get to the real world too, but we expect people to code, hence fizzbuzz.

Greg can give you fizzbuzz as fast as he can write it, in multiple languages. Bob could probably do it with help, and it wouldn't be pretty, and that's in *his language of choice*. Ask them to write it on paper, give them an IDE (Greg doesn't even bother to *use* an IDE), doesn't matter.

So US universities create some of the problem by accepting and then graduating individuals who just can't cut it in industry, and whether that's their fault or the student's or the parents' is more of a philosophical question.

I also suspect but cannot prove that a lot of the debate about whether or not the US has a STEM shortage revolves around this point: employers unable to find qualified candidates say there is one and unqualified graduates who can't find a job say there isn't.

Comment: I am confused by your point. If Bob found a job, that means the universities are doing things right, no? (30 years ago in my country it was expected that uni-graduates have no job-related skills or experience, but know a lot and can think well etc.) Apparenently, Bob can cut it in industry (maybe not in your company).

Comment: @guest finding isn't keeping, and my employer isn't that selective. Just because somebody somewhere was desperate enough to hire him doesn't mean he's qualified or can cut it. Bob is either going to have to learn on his own time what he should have learned when he was younger, all while balancing the demands of working full time at a job he isn't qualified for. It's not enviable. Not to mention the impact of current world events.

Comment: You are making points here that people should learn things like that while they are younger.  While many companies see it this way (obviously every company wants someone who learns everything while the company does not have to pay for that) it is not obvious for me while "Bob should have to learn it on their own time". The Academia perspective is "we teach theory, companies should teach the pratice things themselves". It is not at all clear who is right here. (And we still don't know Bob cannot keep his job or that his company doesn't teach him.)

Comment: @guest ah I think I see where you're going with this now. I think I didn't explain my point well enough. My point about college is that *most programs aren't hard enough to filter out mediocre performers*. Greg would do fine in plenty of other disciplines, Bob might have struggled no matter what major he picked. Whether or not college *should* be in the business of weeding is a whole other question. And just so this is clarified as well: when I say "mediocre performers", I mean something more like non-fizzbuzzers than "not good enough for Google".

Comment: It is not necessarily merit that people "never applied for a job". Those people are highly advantaged. Genius-level people from poor environments have a hard time getting a cashier's job at Target with no experience, not because they are not capable of running the company with the right training, but because they don't have the same advantages. They work their way up the long way, apply for many job, land those jobs, and play the game. Often during the beginning they are rejected many times, not due to lack of skill, but lack of experience.

Comment: @workaddict you're not wrong per se (although you're totally wrong in this one specific instance), but what does that have to do with point? I'm talking about college and filtering out mediocre candidates. This isn't the time or place to discuss broader societal inequities.

Comment: I'm not "totally wrong in this instance" because I allowed for the possibility that **some** people get jobs without applying because they are capable. But many, if not most, do not get jobs even when applying many times, even if they are highly skilled and capable. BTW you don't have a monopoly on speech, so if commenters see it to be relevant, then it is relevant. Nonetheless, good post though.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Greg is an enthusiast who made his hobby his job and Bob is a professional who works to enjoy his other interests. Both is fine. Sometimes enthusiasts are great because they soaked up their job knowledge from childhood, but sometimes they're not because they are way too much flying in their own spaceship lacking any way to think outside their box and appear bone-headed or don't fit in a team. Yes, having good enthusiasts is often great, but those are really the rare cherry. And no expecting work outside work is not reasonable.

Comment: In short, I don't see any indication that Bob is generally gonna be a bad hire or have a hard time. He might need more initial training, but he seems to professionally do what is required of him in his professional capacity. Sounds like a good baseline. Now, he might also lack drive, then he would not fit for some kinds of jobs, but on the other hand could then perfectly fit for others that drive a gung-ho enthusiast crazy. So improvement suggestion: perhaps focus more on different types of graduates with different level of practical experience (theorist vs practical guy, enthusiast etc.).

Comment: @FrankHopkins I agree with you that Greg's level of enthusiasm/dedication is supererogatory. But I think you missed my point: Bob isn't really learning to program. Bob is just checking the checkboxes on a list. More crucially, Bob (at least at that time) had *no idea that actually learning a craft is a thing*. The idea that the real world does not give a **** about what checkboxes you ticked off was completely alien. Whether you blame university for fostering that dynamic or merely think they take advantage where they can, it's a problem. So it's not *just* that he needs a bit extra practice.

Answer (score 6):

> Are a large proportion of programming job applicants unable to
> implement FizzBuzz (or a similarly simple task)?

Yes. I can't think of a single client, friend or my own interview process that was not plagued with that issue where simplest of technical tests, without access to google the answer, do not sieve out majority of candidates.

> Are most comp-sci graduates really unable to implement FizzBuzz in an
> interview?

That I don't think is possible to answer as this isn't as obvious and would require some careful data measuring across that specific demographics.

Comment: And is 199 out of 200 applicicants realistic for you?

Comment: @guest in some companies that had virtually no before-test filter, that is not far off. People see big developer wages and chance it, had builders of all sorts come and try their luck, despite having literally 0 experience.

Comment: `sieve out majority of candidates`  And this is what I think makes FizzBuzz a good interview question.  A candidate can't win an interview with a FizzBuzz answer, but they sure lose one.  This helps quickly weed out the bad candidates.

Comment: I've never done resume screening, so I can't speak for the entire pool of applicants, but in the hundreds of interviews I've done, only a small number couldn't pass the fizzbuzz test. In fact it seems to me that if you are interviewing that many applicants, in indicates a failure in earlier parts of the pipeline.

Comment: @stannius while on the off topic side, it's not without merit. While CV screening certainly eases the workload, you will miss out on some fantastic people whose cv is not impressive, often enough because they cannot write a good CV.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot confirm whether the statistics are true or not, but maybe I can suggest a reasonable explanation for this. Most programming courses in university do little to no programming at all, and a student can get by with little to no programming by opting only for theory courses. The problem is, unless the university is smart and directly provides it, most courses are made by professors, and these professors do not spend their time learning the latest frameworks or interview questions, they research and teach their field to the students, mainly covering theory. Most courses are not there to drill programming exercises or leet-code problems, and lectures that do that tend to be ineffective - how exactly are you going to make the student learn hours of Java in their own time, since lectures are not long enough to babysit them, if they don't want to do it? In short, one must learn programming themselves in their own time to get on top of things, and this may explain why graduates may fumble at a fizz buzz question if they didn't prepare for it.

Comment: Well, if the Student applies for a programmer position in Java instead of an unpaid internship, then it is not too much to ask that he knows PROGRAMMING and has Java experience.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

Directly quoting your link http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/01/dont-overthink-fizzbuzz.html

> UPDATE: If you think that I just claimed that 199 out of 200 working programmers cannot code, stop immediately and either read my follow-up explaining the math, or read Joel’s article on why companies aren’t as picky as they think they are. Thank you.

Comment: But there is this math explaining that the bad appliciants apply over and over; however there is also the other statement in OP's post that the majority cannot program

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers - anxiety is a very real thing for some. And by that I mean those with anxiety problems will feel much more anxious under the conditions of the interview. Yes you have pressure and deadlines in the actual job but we are accustomed to that, have people to bounce our ideas off, and can go deep inside our heads to solve problems if we need to. I for one have never mastered it well even though if you were to talk to people I have worked with they would have good things to say about the work I have done. But trying to talk and think at the same time on a whiteboard with strangers and the clock is ticking just freaks me the eff out on some primal level

Answer (score 0):

> Are a large proportion of programming job applicants unable to implement FizzBuzz (or a similarly simple task)?

Obviously, a reliable statistic does not exist. The opinion of 2-3-10 people is not enough for a believable generalization.

However, "unable" might be too strong a word. Closer to the reality would be (according to my limited experience) that (would be) programmers *have troubles* implementing the FizzBuzz problem. With some hints and some support, or using longer time, some (many) of them succeed to implement it.

> On the blog Coding Horror, Jeff Atwood quotes individuals as saying that a large number of programming job applicants are unable to implement FizzBuzz. Why Can't Programmers.. Program?

That is the opinion of one person out of several billions. Does he have a believable statistic to support his claim?

> Like me, the author is having trouble with the fact that 199 out of 200 applicants for every programming job can't write code at all. I repeat: they can't write any code whatsoever.

Can anyone show a study supporting the "199 out of 200" claim?

> The author he's referring to is Imran, who is evidently turning away lots of programmers who can't write a simple program:

Again, the experience of only one person out of several billions.

> The majority of comp sci graduates can't. I've also seen self-proclaimed senior programmers take more than 10-15 minutes to write a solution.

That makes a sad-but-true observation of the education system in this world. As long as the purpose of universities is to make profit, they will accept and promote people with below-standard abilities. I would love to see a research targeting to find out the percent of people who deserve their diploma at the end of their studies. Maybe "199 out of 200", maybe not.

> Most good programmers should be able to write out on paper a program which does this in a under a couple of minutes.

Considering the simplicity of the problem, I mostly agree. In other contexts, testing a programmer on paper is kind of dumb.

> Is there something wrong with our colleges? Are people panicking?

I am not sure I understand. Which "colleagues"? Which "people"?

> Is it a good thing to ask in an interview?

It depends. If a company wants to quickly filter out the "garbage", then yes. If the company uses this problem to pick the best candidate, then definitely no.

---

I was tested a couple of times with this problem. I had no problem, I finished in just a few minutes, using only 2 "if" statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start at the bottom:

> **Is there something wrong with our colleges?**

Yes, the degree used to be "Math and computer science", and Calculus was a required course, as well as logic classes.  In the late 1990s, with Y2K looming over us, programmers were needed and the math requirement was loosened, unfortunately, it was never restored.

But, the problem doesn't stop there.

The title used to be "Programmer/Analyst", now it's "Developer" and people are referred to as "coders" and not programmers any longer, and with good reason.  There is a distinct difference between the two.

Then, there is the availability of resources that make for lazy thinking.  Those of us who started with a command line interface and no internet beyond the rudiments of using telnet to get into a BBS or using USENET and the like, we had to figure things out on our own.  We had to buy books and manuals, and pour through them trying to figure out where our mistakes were.

This has been replaced by a Google search, and code snippets here and there on various sites where people just cut and paste the code without ever writing it, or more to the point UNDERSTANDING it.

> **Are people panicking?**

Some are, yes, but that's not the problem, IMO

> **Is it a good thing to ask in an interview?**

I would say yes, but more to see how they reacted than anything else.  The question is less relevant than it was, and there are very few real life situations where understanding the modulus operator is going to make or break you.  But it does show how a person reacts to the problem.

When I am interviewing, I am less interested with the answer than I am with the approach and the reactions.  In fact, knowing that this question trips up so many people, I would ask it just to see how people react to failure, as that tells me far more than how someone reacts when everything is going well.  I have absolutely no problem working with someone who is technically deficient so long as they are  **WILLING AND ABLE TO LEARN**

Then of course, some people are just dumb.

As George Carlin once said "Think of how stupid the average person is, then realize that half the people are dumber than that"

That is literally half the issue right there:  **50% of people are below average**

But, the question to ask is not are you getting the upper 25, 15 or 5% but if if you NEED someone of that technical level.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a problem. I personally don't like eyeballs on me when I'm coding, but if you're asked to write it on paper, the interviewer is not expecting it to compile, just that it conceptually makes sense, and I would absolutely expect a candidate to be able to do that. Whenever I've given tests to candidates, I've always put more stock by how they discuss it afterwards, how they interpreted the problem and what they planned to do than by what they actually churned out in however long they were given.

Comment: So is "199 in 200 appliciants" in your opinion correct or not?